# c# web service (asmx) objects

Tags: c#, .net, asmx

I have a local console app using a DLL that contains models.
I have created a remote web service (using the same DLL and models).
When the client (local console app) consumes the remote asmx wsdl, all the objects that the public returns are not "mapped" in the local models.
How can I use it as a local object (because now all objects came from service are using different namespace and I need to rewrite all code...

[image: images]

Comment: I have no answer for you, but I am curious. Who is forcing you to build an asmx web service? It is a technology very outdated.

Comment: No one. Sure we can use REST. I just found it as a solution rather than re-write whole enterprise applications (changing from access methods located in lib , to REST). Serialize deserialize will take me 8 monthes to rewrite all.

Comment: Perhaps, but implementing everywhere this approach will cost you a lot as well, and from my experience, it is a nightmare if you need to change something in the contract. At the end you will have a weaky solution with an obsolete technology. But it is your call. Good luck.

Comment: maybe AutoMapper could help to you